# How to get nth occurrence in a string?

Tags: strings, bashful

I get a string from an external program, and I would like to get each part of that string:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bashful}

\begin{document}

% Test.sh would do echo "4 8 15 16 23 42"
\let\data{\splice{./test.sh}}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \getOccurences{2}{\data} %15
    \item \getOccurences{5}{\data} %23
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The information read from `stdout` is a series of numbers space separated.

How should I implement the `\getOccurences` macro?

Comment: Since you already load `bashful`, why not count the occurrences in bash?

Comment: Because I am not using bash. This is just a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Comment: Would it be safe to assume that your external program writes a file containing (say) `4 8 15 16 23 42` and that you want to extract data therefrom?

Comment: My external program is C executable which contain a `printf("%d", a[i])` in a loop.

Comment: `\let\data{`  defines `\data` to be `{`

Comment: can you provide an example that does not require `--shell-escape`  it is not reasonable to ask people to run  tex fragments copied from the internet with shell escape enabled

Comment: Well, you can replace `\splice{...}` with `4 8 15 16 23 42` and you have it.

Comment: if you have control over the format and can  use commas not spaces you could use expl3 clist item directly

Comment: @nowox no as it would still error on the unmatched `}`

Comment: If you're willing to learn TeX programming, you can use `seq_set_split` and `seq_item` from expl3. Otherwise, even if we provide an answer you would need to modify it to take the input from your command instead of e.g. hard coded constant that we do, then maybe do it incorrectly and complain the answer does not work etc. because you don't give a MWE, which is a problem.

Answer (score 2):

The `xstring` package has a macro `StrBetween[n,m]{full string}{string A}{string B}` that may help here. It will select the substring between the nth occurrence of string A and the mth occurrence of string B. In this case you can set both string A and string B to be a space and extract the string between the 2nd and 3rd space to get 15 and the string between the 4th and 5th space to get 23.

The second part of the question is to get the external output into a format that `xstring` can handle. This is a bit tricky. `\splice` is doing a lot under the hood that causes trouble when expanding the macro for string processing. A better alternative is to use `\bashStdout` as defined by `bashful` that captures the output of the last `\bash \END` block as a plain string. The only problem here is that spaces have category code 12 which also confuses `xstring`. As a solution you can 'flatten' the string using `\detokenize`. This has the added advantage that you can use `\edef` which expands the argument, allowing for other `\bash \END` blocks (which will overwrite `\bashStdout`) in between the execution and the actual use of the values.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bashful}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\bash
echo "4 8 15 16 23 42"
\END
\edef\data{\detokenize\expandafter{\bashStdout}}
All data: \data

\begin{itemize}
    \item \StrBetween[2,3]{\data}{ }{ } %15
    \item \StrBetween[4,5]{\data}{ }{ } %23
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You probably want to write edef data instead of def data. // remark, expl3 equivalent statement is `\str_set:NV \data \bashStdout`

Comment: @user202729 just `\edef\data{\bashStdout}` does not solve the catcode problem, while `\def{\detokenize ...}` works fine with `xstring`. Is there another reason to prefer `edef` here (besides it being a bit cleaner perhaps)?

Comment: I mean `\edef\data{\detokenize\expandafter{\bashStdout}}`.

Comment: Because... for example if you do another bash command bashStdout will be rewritten? Also only need to detokenize once (alternative is to insert two expandafter in, but these expandafter are ugly)

Comment: Ah yes, very good point. I'll edit.

Comment: How to you get the first element `4` with this? I tried \StrBetweek[0,1]

Comment: @nowox the first element is not between two spaces, it is before the first space, so you need another command `\StrBefore{\data}{ }`. Similarly the last number would be `\StrBehind[5]{\data}{ }`.

Comment: Alternatively you can put a leading and trailing space in the `\data` macro and use `\StrBetween` for all items, i.e., `\edef\data{\space\detokenize\expandafter{\bashStdout}\space}`.

Answer (score 2):

This answer addresses how to parse the string, once you have inputted it.  For this example, therefore, I merely define the string using `\def`.  I use the `listofitems` package to create an array of the individual string elements.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{bashful}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\setsepchar{ }
\ignoreemptyitems
\begin{document}

% Test.sh would do echo "4 8 15 16 23 42"
%\let\data{\splice{./test.sh}}
\def\data{4 8 15 16 23 42}

\readlist\mylist{\data}

\mylist[3] should be 15

\mylist[5] should be 23

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work with the output from bash. I tried to put `echo 4 8 15 16 23 42` in \splice.

Comment: @nowox This answer works if you first detokenize the bash output like in my answer, i.e., `\edef\data{\detokenize\expandafter{\bashStdout}}\readlist\mylist{\data}\mylist[3]`. And it is also a better solution than my answer because the indexing is much more straightforward.

Comment: @nowox Also, the `\mylist[3]`, etc. array elements *fully expand* into their original values.